# Why my WordPress plugin options array not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

My php variable `$ex_product_ids`  which contain value `18,63,72,91` & I have checked it using `echo $ex_product_ids` it show the value of my input field of my plugin correctly but when I want to use it in a array like `$target_products = array($ex_product_ids);` its not working only return result for the first array item.

**here is the code** not working

```
$_options = get_option( 'license_page_option' ); 
$ex_product_ids = $_options['ex_product_ids_warranty']; // it have value 18,63,72,91
$target_products = array($ex_product_ids);
```

but if I manually use those ids like `$target_products = array(18,63,72,91);` it works

I'm sorry if i'm doing anything wrong ! please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) because current value can be the simple string and you need to convert it to an array of values.

```
$_options = get_option( 'license_page_option' ); 
$ex_product_ids = $_options['ex_product_ids_warranty']; // it have value 18,63,72,91
$target_products = explode(",",$ex_product_ids);
print_r($target_products); // array(18,63,72,91)
```